# Is there a better way to add multiple mocked interactions?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I am seeking a better way to add multiple interactions of the same method within a class.

Given a list of objects, I want to perform a filter based upon these objects, and with the remaining objects I want to add Spock interactions for each of them

My best working implementation (using Java8 streams with for-loop to add interactions):

```
SomeClassA classA = Mock() {

   def listOfDesiredObjects = listOfObjects
      .stream()
      .filter({i -> i != someObject})
      .map({i -> new DesiredObject(i)})
      .collect(Collectors.toList())

   for (int i = 0; i < listOfDesiredObjects.size(); i++) {
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, listOfDesiredObjects.get(i) as Type1) >> {
         return someMockedObject
      }
   }

   methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, someObject as Type1) >> {
      return someDifferentMockedObject
   }
}
```

I have tried the following but they either do not compile or are just messy (in my opinion):

The following will return a `Groovyc: Interaction is missing a target` error:

```
SomeClassA classA = Mock() {

   def listOfDesiredObjects = listOfObjects
      .stream()
      .filter({i -> i != someObject})
      .map({i -> new DesiredObject(i)})
      .forEach({i -> methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, listOfDesiredObjects.get(i) as Type1) >> {
         return someMockedObject
      }})

   methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, someObject as Type1) >> {
      return someDifferentMockedObject
   }
}
```

This is just bad:

```
SomeClassA classA = Mock() {

   methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, listOfDesiredObjects.get(0) as Type1) >> {
      return someMockedObject
   }

   methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, listOfDesiredObjects.get(1) as Type1) >> {
      return someMockedObject
   }

   // {n} more interactions

   methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, someObject as Type1) >> {
      return someDifferentMockedObject
   }
}
```

For future reference (how I ended up leveraging the argument matchers):

```
def classToMock = Mock() {
   methodToMock(_ as Type0, _ as Type1, _ as Type2) >> { Type0 a, Type1 objectToCompare, Type2 c ->
      listOfObjects
         .stream()
         .map({i -> someHelperMethod(i)})
         .filter({i -> i == objectToCompare})
         .map({i -> desiredObject })
         .findFirst()
         .orElse({i -> otherObject})
   }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed your test case, as it's unclear why, for example, you can't just use `_` and an indeterminate number of calls. In the immediate case, a trivial rephrasing would be `listOfDesiredObjects.forEach { methodToMock(_, it) >> someMockedObject }` (do read the Spock documentation on how to write individual interaction calls, both for simple value returns and argument matching, and the Groovy docs for collection manipulations).

Comment: @chrylis I need to do this because I want to return a different object for the argument matching the case of `Type1` == `someObject`. I updated the original question with some clarification on this.

Comment: So just use `methodMock(_, { it != someObject }) >> usualMock`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User *chrylis* is right, the solution is actually quite simple if you use argument matching. I have recreated your situation according to your (pseudo) code including dummy classes so as to show you different ways to simplify your approach:

Here are the crucial bits from the alternatives:

```groovy
  def "simplified test with two distinct cases"() {
    given:
    def someObject = new DesiredObject("C")
    SomeClassA classA = Mock() {
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_, !someObject) >> someMockedObject
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_, someObject) >> someDifferentMockedObject
    }
    // (...)
  }

  def "simplified test with special and default case"() {
    given:
    def someObject = new DesiredObject("C")
    SomeClassA classA = Mock() {
      // Attention, this only works if the special case is defined before the default one
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_, someObject) >> someDifferentMockedObject
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(*_) >> someMockedObject
    }
    // (...)
  }

  def "simplified test with dynamic stub method"() {
    given:
    def someObject = new DesiredObject("C")
    SomeClassA classA = Mock() {
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(*_) >> { a, b -> b == someObject ? someDifferentMockedObject : someMockedObject }
    }
    // (...)
  }
```

And here is the full code (just copy, paste and run):

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q57210075

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.util.stream.Collectors

class ConditionalMockCreationTest extends Specification {

  class Type0 {}

  class DesiredObject {
    String name

    DesiredObject(String name) {
      this.name = name
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
      "DesiredObject('$name')"
    }

    boolean equals(o) {
      if (this.is(o)) return true
      if (getClass() != o.class) return false
      DesiredObject that = (DesiredObject) o
      if (name != that.name) return false
      return true
    }

    int hashCode() {
      return (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0)
    }
  }

  class SomeClassA {
    DesiredObject methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(Type0 type0, DesiredObject desiredObject) {
      return new DesiredObject("default")
    }
  }

  def someMockedObject = Mock(DesiredObject) {
    toString() >> "some mocked object"
  }
  def someDifferentMockedObject = Mock(DesiredObject) {
    toString() >> "some different mocked object"
  }

  def "original test"() {
    given:
    def listOfObjects = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    def someObject = "C"
    SomeClassA classA = Mock() {
      def listOfDesiredObjects = listOfObjects
        .stream()
        .filter({ i -> i != someObject })
        .map({ i -> new DesiredObject(i) })
        .collect(Collectors.toList())

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfDesiredObjects.size(); i++) {
        methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, listOfDesiredObjects.get(i) as DesiredObject) >> {
          return someMockedObject
        }
      }

      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_ as Type0, new DesiredObject(someObject)) >> {
        return someDifferentMockedObject
      }
    }

    expect: "normal object yields normal result"
    new SomeClassA().methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "DesiredObject('default')"

    and: "mocked objects yield predefined mock behaviour"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("B")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("C")).toString() == "some different mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("D")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("E")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    // Undefined case -> no stubbed method -> mock returns null
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("XXX")) == null
  }

  def "simplified test with two distinct cases"() {
    given:
    def someObject = new DesiredObject("C")
    SomeClassA classA = Mock() {
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_, !someObject) >> someMockedObject
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_, someObject) >> someDifferentMockedObject
    }

    expect: "normal object yields normal result"
    new SomeClassA().methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "DesiredObject('default')"

    and: "mocked objects yield predefined mock behaviour"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("B")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("C")).toString() == "some different mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("D")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("E")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("XXX")).toString() == "some mocked object"
  }

  def "simplified test with special and default case"() {
    given:
    def someObject = new DesiredObject("C")
    SomeClassA classA = Mock() {
      // Attention, this only works if the special case is defined before the default one
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(_, someObject) >> someDifferentMockedObject
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(*_) >> someMockedObject
    }

    expect: "normal object yields normal result"
    new SomeClassA().methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "DesiredObject('default')"

    and: "mocked objects yield predefined mock behaviour"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("B")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("C")).toString() == "some different mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("D")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("E")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("XXX")).toString() == "some mocked object"
  }

  def "simplified test with dynamic stub method"() {
    given:
    def someObject = new DesiredObject("C")
    SomeClassA classA = Mock() {
      methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(*_) >> { a, b -> b == someObject ? someDifferentMockedObject : someMockedObject }
    }

    expect: "normal object yields normal result"
    new SomeClassA().methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "DesiredObject('default')"

    and: "mocked objects yield predefined mock behaviour"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("A")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("B")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("C")).toString() == "some different mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("D")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("E")).toString() == "some mocked object"
    classA.methodIWantToMockMultipleTimes(new Type0(), new DesiredObject("XXX")).toString() == "some mocked object"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that equality comparison is the default, so `{it == someObject}` can be replaced with just `someObject`.

Comment: Thanks, of course, I did not optimise that away and made it more verbose, just like you in your first comment. But I have updated the code according to your suggestion, also using `!someObject` and using `*_` (any argument list with any number of parameters) instead of `_, _` (any argument list consisting of exactly two parameters). If the OP needs to be more specific or type-safe he can still do it just like in his own sample code.

Comment: If `!someObject` works, then that would be a surprise to me; I'd expect that to simply flip Groovy truthiness.

Comment: Nice that I can surprise you, see [Spock manual, chapter "argument constraints"](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints).

Comment: That's a little unsettling but neat to know, thanks!

Comment: @chrylis & kriegaex: thank you for your help! Using these examples, I was able to simplify my code!